# Is there any significance to the bell chiming in the Great Northern Hotel in Twin Peaks: The Return?

Tags: twin-peaks

In part nine of *Twin Peaks: The Return*, Beverley (Ashley Judd) and Ben (Richard Beymer) search the hotel because they hear what Ben describes as a [monastery bell](https://twinpeaks.fandom.com/wiki/Part_9). Do they ever explain what the noise actually is? I know Lynch and Frost use a lot of symbolism on the show and don't explain every plot point, but I was curious if anyone knew if it has ever been revealed what the significance or purpose of the bell chimes were.

Comment: I think they hear it again in the second-last episode, near the door Agent Cooper goes through at the Great Northern (sorry, just going from memory). I don't really know what the significance is. My guess is that it is a reminder that, whatever other weirdness there is in the world of Twin Peaks, at the heart it is about the tragic death of a girl - don't just move on from that.